# on binary strings without using Ramsey Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Using the Ramsey Theorem

> Let $X$ be some countably infinite set and colour the elements 
>       of $X(n)$ (the subsets of $X$ of size $n$) in $c$ different colours. 
>       Then there exists some infinite subset $M\subset X$ such that the size $n$ 
>       subsets of $M$ all have the same colour.

it's easy to prove the following:

> Given a countably infinite set of infinite binary strings $X$, and a 
>       natural number $n$, then there exists a infinite subset $Y\subset X$ such that 
>       no subset of $Y$ with $n$ elements has XOR sum zero

My question is: there's a way to prove this without using Ramsey?